# Home screen malfunctioned, unable to tap or open any app

Tags: 9.0-pie, home-screen

Phone (Make, Model): Cherry Mobile Flare S8 Pro
Android Version / ROM Name: Android 9
Root: No
Unlocked Bootloader: No

Issue:
While I was browsing on Kiwi Browser as always and changing between apps, my phone just lagged. I tried to press the home screen during the lag but all my apps on the home screen seem to have disappeared, including the clock and other widgets. It's an empty screen with only the wallpaper.

Every few seconds, the apps on the home screen will show but after a few seconds, it will disappear again. When the apps on the home screen show, I can't press or tap any of them. Every time I do that, the home screen disappears again.

I restarted multiple times and even tried to reboot in safe mode but to no avail. It's still the same thing. I uninstalled a random app in safe mode to see if it works but nothing happened, the issue is still there.

[image: Uninstalled the first app I saw in safe mode.]

However, I managed to find a way to access the apps by pulling the top bar and pressing the settings button, going to the apps, and then clicking on "downloaded from Google Play" which opens the Google Play Store. This allows me to open and use any apps downloaded from the Play Store. However, this means I cannot open them unless I try to update them first.

When I tried to normal boot after uninstalling the first app I saw in the safe mode, crazy stuff happened. My home screen suddenly turned messy and the arrangement became chaotic. (It was supposed to be three rows of app folders.)

I tried to open the apps on the home screen but instead of the app opening, the tiny buttons below which show the number of swipe pages on the home screen increased explosively, which can be seen in the second image.

[image: Suddenly many home screen pages!]

I don't really know what to do here, I don't want to factory reset and lose everything. I'm too broke to afford any phone repair either. So it would be highly appreciated if I could get some help.

I took a 34-second video recording that shows the broken home screen here:
https://streamable.com/rnpip9

Comment: Considering the age of the phone your flash memory may be defect and has switched to read-only mode. If you connect the phone via USB to a PC, can you write a new file on the phone that survives a reboot? Anyway backup all your data to the connected PC as there is a chance that the flash memory will fail.